# Inserting Search box into header image

Tags: css, search, web

I am looking to insert/move my search bar into my header image similar to the example below. If someone had a minute to show me how to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time. Here is the link to my website http://www.jobspark.ca/

Chris

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add your search box inside

```
<div id="logo" class="image">
    ...
    <h1>
      ...
    </h1>
    "search box code goes here"
</div>
```

Give an id in the search div and Finally position using CSS padding.

Comment: Should also mention that the image should be appiled to the `#logo` with `background` and `background-size` CSS properties.

Comment: yeah absolutely... but somehow(by inspecting the page i'm unable to find from where the background image comes) the background is already filled through out the div, is it necessary to mention here?

Comment: I am using a Squarespace template and have limited access to the html. Is there a way I can accomplish this using purely CSS?

Comment: Just overwrite CSS of the template where and all needed or else keep a separate CSS and include in your head tag and proceed designing

Comment: Do you have an example of the CSS that I would include?

Comment: I'm not having any example for that...create a CSS file, put the classes & id's in the div's of your HTML you want to modify, give the appropriate styles to those classes & id's in CSS to get your desired style...

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the background image into body tag. set no repeat, use background-size to 100% width.

```
 example:

    body{
           backgroud-image:url() no-repeat center;
           background-size: --;
         }
      HTML STRUCTURE:



 <div id="header">
        <div ="#"> 
           <h1></h1> //float:left
           <div id="menu"></div> //float:right;

         </div>

        <div ="search-box">
             <form>

             </form> //use margin and padding for keep it center;
        </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: I am using a Squarespace template and have limited access to the html. Is there a way I can accomplish this using purely CSS?

Comment: i don't think that you can do it with css. can you please share your tamplate.